# Windows-7 upgrade?

Tags: windows-7

My Specs: Gateway FX Series FX4710-UB003A Desktop PC Core 2 Quad Q9300 (2.50GHz) 6GB DDR2 640GB HDD Windows Vista Home Premium 64-bit. My DVD-ROM drive is broken. I recently started up my computer to find I am having a boot/BCD error. I have heard several suggestions to solve my problem, and they sound reasonable enough, but I was wondering if it would be worth it to just take the opportunity to upgrade my system to windows 7. Would I be wasting my money? Would it be a better investment to just buy a new PC? I don't really need any of the data on my system, but I need a working PC. What's the smartest move here?

Comment: It's an opportunity to upgrade to Windows 7, but also to upgrade to Linux? :) It's completely free, so I think it's at least worth a try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your system to `Windows 7 Ultimate` This is the best move as you stated you were using `Windows Vista Home Premium` previously.

You can use Removable disk (Pendrive) for upgrading or formatting your system because your `DVD-ROM drive` is broken. Another option is Linux. you can go for that if you want.

Comment: Unless you specifically need the features offered, then Ultimate is usually overkill. Best to look at the comparison chart (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Comparison_chart) and determine whether you need to go any higher than Home Premium. Many people won't and can save some money.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can recreate bcd using 'EasyBCD' application if you could get into os on that machine. Or it can be done using similar applications on a different machine with your hdd connected.